# Google CSE: "File uploading is not successful" with valid XML

Tags: xml, google-custom-search, xml-configuration

I'm setting up a UTF-8 google custom search engine. I've written the XML context file but it will not upload.

I've run the XML through several validators and had others look at it, but there don't seem to be any problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomSearchEngine id="3yydrop0z2m" creator="007729199335892686358" keywords="Maine, school" language="en" encoding="UTF-8" autocompletions="true">
    <Title>School Search Engine</Title>
    <Description>Searches Public School Pages in Maine</Description>
    <Annotations>
        <Annotation about="www.facebook.com/*">
            <Label name="_cse_3yydrop0z2m"></Label>
        </Annotation>
        <Annotation about="https://twitter.com/*">
            <Label name="_cse_3yydrop0z2m"></Label>
        </Annotation>
    </Annotations>
    <Context>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem title="Twitter">
                <Label name="twitter" mode="BOOST" weight="0.5"></Label>
             </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem title="Maine">
                <Label name="maine" mode="BOOST" weight="0.7"></Label>
            </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem title="High School">
                <Label name="high" mode="BOOST" weight="0.8">
                    <Rewrite>high school OR academy OR high</Rewrite>
                </Label>
            </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem title="Middle School">
                <Label name="middle" mode="BOOST" weight="0.7">
                    <Rewrite>middle school OR middle</Rewrite>
                </Label>
            </FacetItem>
         </Facet>
         <Facet>
             <FacetItem title="Elementary School">
                <Label name="elementary" mode="BOOST" weight="0.7">
                    <Rewrite>primary OR grammar school OR elementary</Rewrite>
                </Label>
             </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem name="museum">
                <Label name="museum" mode="ELIMINATE"></Label>
            </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem name="town hall">
                <Label name="town hall" mode="ELIMINATE">
                    <Rewrite>community OR city council</Rewrite>
                </Label>
            </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <Facet>
            <FacetItem name="other state">
                <Label name="other state" mode="ELIMINATE">
                    <Rewrite>Alabama OR Alaska</Rewrite>
                </Label>
            </FacetItem>
        </Facet>
        <BackgroundLabels>
            <Label name="https://www.Facebook.com/*" mode="FILTER"/>
            <Label name="https://www.Twitter.com/*" mode="FILTER"/>
            <Label name="_cse_3yydrop0z2m" mode="FILTER"/>
            <Label name="_cse_exclude_3yydrop0z2m" mode="ELIMINATE"/>
        </BackgroundLabels>
    </Context>
    <LookAndFeel element_layout="8" theme="7" custom_theme="false" url_length="full" element_branding="show" enable_cse_thumbnail="true" promotion_url_length="full" font="2">
        <Logo url="http://inet.state.me.us/education/communications/images/informal01R-200.png" height="50"/>
        <Colors url="#3366cc" background="#FFFFFF" border="#162C40" title="#274F73" text="#000000" visited="ffbd10" visible_hover="#162C40" visible_active="#0000CC"/>
        <Promotions/>
        <SearchControls/>
        <Results border_color="FFFFFF" border_hover_color="#162C40" background_color="#FFFFFF" background_hover_color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LookAndFeel>
    <ImageSearchSettings enable="false"/>
    <autocomplete_settings/>
</CustomSearchEngine>
```

What are some potential issues that could be at the root of this? I know I'm not supposed to upload all of the code but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations and Context are managed separately and need to be uploaded in different XML files.  Try removing the `<Annotations>` block from your XML.